# anacondaをデフォルトに設定し、jupyter notebookを起動したい

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, pyenv

初めて質問させていただきます。知識不足で申し訳ありません。
pyenvをインストールし、anacondaもインストールした後、

```
$ pyenv rehash
$ pyenv global anaconda3-4.3.1
```

とし、anaconda3-4.3.1をデフォルトに設定したいのですが、

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
* anaconda3-4.3.1 (set by /Users/myname/.pyenv/version)
```

と設定できているはずなのに、

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

となります。

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10

$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  6 2017, 23:53:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

$ jupyter notebook
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

コマンドからjupyter notebookを起動させたいです。どうしたら良いでしょうか。

```
$ /Users/myname/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/bin/jupyter_mac.command
```

と打てば一応jupyter notebookは起動します。

jupyter notebookだけで起動させたいのです。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`eval "$(pyenv init -)"` をしていないのかもしれません。

たとえば Bash を使っている場合 `~/.bashrc` などを見て以下に相当する行が含まれているか確認し、その後シェルを読み込み直してください (これらの設定は、通常 pyenv をインストールしたときの手順に書かれているはずです)。

```sh
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

この設定がないと `$PATH` が認識されず、システム側の Python 環境が選択されてしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

どこか例えばホームディレクトリ等に **.python-version** というファイルはないでしょうか？ そちらが優先されて pynenv global が上手く効かないという事例があるようです。

http://qiita.com/1234224576/items/11ad3509fe4b0a9a33ed